# pylatex append to an already made Section

Tags: python, latex, pylatex

I have a LaTeX file that fits a certain template, lets say it looks like this :

```tex
\title{test}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\section{Developement}
\section{Conclusion}

\end{document}
```

Now, I want to open that said LaTeX file and write into specific section.
Imaginary code would be something like that :

```py
import pylatex
with open('test.tex') as file : 
    file['introduction'].append("this is my introduction")
    file['conclusion'].append(pylatex.utils.italic('my italic conclusion...'))
```

How can I do that ?